# How can I cause a JLabel to disappear after a period of time?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlabel

I have an issue with my program.  I have a button handler that I would like to make a JLabel disappear, then wait one second, then cause a second JLabel to disappear.  I thought my code would work, it does a delay, however both JLabels disappear once the method finishes.  They disappear at the same time and this isn't what I want.  My code is below.  Thank you for your help!

```
private void jButton14ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    String numInputStr = inputBox.getText();
    int numInput = Integer.parseInt(numInputStr);

    inputBox.setText("");

    if (numInput == 1) {
        coin1.setVisible(false);
        c1Visible = false;
    } else if (numInput == 2) {
        coin1.setVisible(false);
        c1Visible = false;
        coin2.setVisible(false);
        c2Visible = false;

    } else if (numInput == 3) {
        coin1.setVisible(false);
        c1Visible = false;
        coin2.setVisible(false);
        c2Visible = false;
        coin3.setVisible(false);
        c3Visible = false;
    } else {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input, try again");

    }

    jButton14.setVisible(false);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception E) {

    }

    if ((c1Visible == false) && (c2Visible == true) && (c3Visible == true)) {
        coin2.setVisible(false);
        coin3.setVisible(false);
        coin4.setVisible(false);
    } else if ((c2Visible == false) && (c3Visible == true) && (c1Visible == false)) {
        coin3.setVisible(false);
        coin4.setVisible(false);

    } else if ((c3Visible == false) && (c4Visible == true)) {
        coin4.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong, please try again");
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to use a Timer for this; calling sleep() in the button's actionPerformed() will block the event thread, preventing anything from happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought my code would work, it does a delay, however both JLabels
>   disappear once the method finishes.

This is a classic Swing concurrency problem, because you call `Thread.sleep()` from the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) which is a single and special thread where Swing event handling takes place and components creation/update should take place too.

If you block this thread your GUI won't be able to repaint itself and will be *freezed* until the thread is ready to process Swing related stuff.

In order to achieve your goal I'd suggest you to use a [Swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to make those labels *disappear* after a given period of time.

For further information about this matter please take a look to:

- [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)